# How can I save the variable answer for a prompt to the file so it saves?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am making a file where you type a "post" and it shows it. How can I make that "post" save so next time I open the file on Chrome it still shows the variable text?

```html
<h3 style="color:teal;padding:8">My Post</h3>
<p id="post" style="padding:8"></p>
<button id="myButton" onclick="var post=prompt('What would you like to say?');document.getElementById('post').innerHTML = post;">Edit!</button>
```

Comment: or local storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Don't use cookies, use local storage instead

Comment: Also, try to use Dom Level 2 listeners instead of inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work like just you want it

```
<h3 style="color:teal;padding:8">My Post</h3>
    <p id="post" style="padding:8"></p>
    <button id="myButton" onclick="var post=prompt('What would you like to say?');document.getElementById('post').innerHTML = post;localStorage.setItem("post", post);">Edit!</button>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('post').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("post");
    </script>
```